# No Files Included in the CartThrob Download Zip

Tags: cartthrob

I'm not seeing any files included in the CartThrob download zip when I download or attempt to view the contents of the zip. I'm having the same issue with a previous license as well. First time I've had this problem. Anyone have any ideas what the issue could be?

Comment: Where are you getting it from - I downloaded it fine from the CT website a few days ago - CT 2.6

Comment: Hey Jeremy. I'm logging into my account and accessing the downloads under Purchased Items on the CT website.